.eps graphic scale to large when exporting from inkscape and ChemDraw
I'm currently trying to set up an latex document, where I include chemical reactions as .eps figures. With the help of the chemnum-package I replace temporary tags inside the figure. The drawings are made with ChemDraw. The problem is, that ChemDraw does not support exporting a selection as an .eps file (at least I have not found this option..). Therefore, I copy the drawn structure to Inkscape and export it as an .eps file. However, when including the .eps file in latex, the figure is always too big. I already tried to change the dpi when exporting the .eps file from Inkscape, but it did not work so far, the figure is always the same size in the final pdf. Scaling the graphics inside latex is not an option, because it has to be exactly the size it has in the ChemDraw. What I think the problem may be, is that the dimensions of the selection get lost when copying from ChemDraw to Inkscape.
I would really appreciate your help!

Wouldn't it be easier to have one ChemDraw file per .eps file that you want to export instead of copying to Inkscape and exporting from there?

If I export an .eps from ChemDraw directly it exports the whole page. When having only one small reaction on it there will be a lot of white space.

I haven't used ChemDraw in quite a while now, but I don't recall exessive margins when directly exporting to eps.

Ok, I've just tried it and it works only when there is one reaction scheme drawn. Then ChemDraw will export the scheme without margins. However, I couldn't export a reaction scheme from a ChemDraw with multiple schemes in it. In this case ChemDraw exports the whole page.

ChemDraw has a setting for EPS files which chooses whether to export a full page - are you on Windows or macOS?

I'm on Windows. Where can I find this setting?
